# Cannot run Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10. When I try to open jupyter notebook from terminal this error occurrs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_trace_v2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

When I checked sqlite3, it is intalled in home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/ and it contains dbapi2.py. Should I somehow reorganize the folders?
PS: When I tried `pip install pysqlite2` another error occurred: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite2 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysqlite2`

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember how exactly I installed the jupyter notebook because it was months ago and I didn't needed it until now (when I found out it is not working)

Comment: `/home/anaconda3` feels like a really weird directory. Is that your local user's home directory (I hope not)? How did you start the the notebook? Are you using a Conda environment?

Comment: I tried import sqlite3 after starting python but it failed with this error: ImportError: /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_trace_v2

Comment: And yes, the anaconda3 directory is in my local user's home directory, I just didn't want to use my surname here

Comment: But why the anaconda3 choice? Is there any Conda involved here?

Comment: And what does `which python` and `which jupyter` yield?

Comment: It yields /home/anaconda3/bin/python and /home/anaconda3/bin/jupyter

And there is probably some conda involved, it is possible I used it for installation of the jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you performed a manual installation of Jupyter (and required dependencies) directly in your home directory.
I'm assuming `/home/anaconda3/` is your home directory, and anaconda3 is just a badly chosen name.

Rename the lib subdirectory:

```
mv lib lib_aside
```

You might want to do something similar for include/ or bin/ directories directly in your home as well (but check first what is in bin/ ; if that is all Python/Jupyter related, or that there's software you actually need that is not default installable).

Comment out any PYTHONPATH setting in your `.bashrc` that points to that lib/ directory (and subdirectories).

Comment out any PATH alteration to the bin/ in your home directory as well.

If you don't need it, comment-out the section with Conda stuff as well.

Install Jupyter from your package manager. E.g.

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook
```

Start a new terminal, and test:

```
which python
which jupyter
```

These should point to `/usr/bin`

Start your notebook:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Thank you for navigating me. I renamed the whole anaconda3 directory and installed the notebook again the way you recommended. It points to /usr/bin/jupyter. However, executing the notebook must be now done with command `jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: The command is probably to not clash with other potential system packages; although `jupyter notebook` works on my 22.04 installation. `python -m jupyter notebook` is an even more guaranteed way to start the notebook, once you know that is the correct `python` executable.